# Error when using callback function inside useEffect reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, socket.io, react-18

I have this code receive data from socket and add to an array.It work fine in the first render but when i change offSet = 2 the offset state outside callback working just fine and changing to 2 but the offset inside callback function still remain 1. please help me

```
const updateSocketData = useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      console.log(offSet)
      if (data.type === TYPE_NORMAL && offSet === 1) {
        Object.keys(data.score).forEach((key) => {
          dataGraph.push(data.score[key])
          if (dataGraph.length > 9) {
            dataGraph.splice(0, 1)
            setDataLabel((dataLabel: any) =>
              dataLabel.filter((_: any, i: any) => i !== 0)
            )
            setGallery((gallery: any) =>
              gallery.filter((_: any, i: any) => i !== 0)
            )
          }
        })
        setDataLabel((dataLabel: any) => [
          ...dataLabel,
          moment(data.created_at).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'),
        ])
        setGallery((gallery: any) => [
          ...gallery,
          { source_url: data.source_url, imageId: data.box_image_id },
        ])
      }
    },
    [dataGraph, dataLabel, gallery, offSet]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
      socket.on(`box_${id}`, updateSocketData)
      console.log(offSet)
  }, [offSet])
```

I have try to put updateSocketData in dependency array of useEffect but it did not work,I expected the state inside the updateSocketData changing like outside